# Schtasks.exe does not accept blank spaces when giving file path

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm rolling out a new python script at the office and to make this run smooth I also made a batch file which will install it, and make it run on user logon.

I use schtasks.exe to schedule a task for this, so here is what i'm trying to run

```
schtasks /create /TN "fooname" /SC ONLOGON /TR "C:\foo - bar\fooscript.exe" /Delay 0005:00
```

The error I get is 0x80070002 which means the file cannot be found. After exporting the task I created, I can see that it separated the first and last bit of the path into

```
<Command>C:\foo</Command>
<Arguments>bar\fooscript.exe</Arguments>
```

I have tried [microsofts own help article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/823093), but no luck. I wish to run this without any arguments regarding fooscript.exe.

Comment: It's the hyphen that's the problem as it is a switch character.

Comment: @bgalea I suspected the hyphen was part of the problem here :) Unfortunately I cannot change the name of the folder, is there a way to like store this in a variable or use quotations cleverly in order to ignore the hyphen?

Comment: See how there is an ampersand after foo in the registry entry at (adapt for your guid) `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{34B086CE-B5DF-42E7-A815-87335E063F24}`. Try using `reg` command to rewrite the key without a &.

Comment: execute `dir \x "c:\foo - bar" which will show you the shortname of the directory. Use that shortname in place of "foo - bar"

Comment: That should be `dir \x "c:\foo*" - the version with the full name will produce a report of that particular directory's contents.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you, this solved the hyphen problem! Got some additional constraints errors, but I believe they where circumstantial, because now it runs perfectly! :)

Comment: I would like to see how the file path is stored when you create the task with the gui.

Comment: @Squashman When created in the wizard the path gets stored as "C:\Users\310176421\Desktop\foo - bar\fooscript.bat", no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Magoo pointed out I was able to use the short name of the folder, which can be accessed with a

```
dir /x
```

tossing back a name like "FOO~1". Using this in my path made it work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry old thread but just found a workaround better than these here.  Put the dir name in a prompt variable and then use the var in the command.

```
 SET fname="c:\path with spaces\target.exe"
 SchTasks [args] /TR %fname%
```

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is

`schtasks /create /TN "fooname" /SC ONLOGON /TR "\"C:\foo - bar\fooscript.exe"" /Delay 0005:00`